# Paragraph writing within subequations and equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs, subequations

i had an issue with writing a paragraph within the equation having subequations as given in snap shot[image: Paragraph within sub-equations]..thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What is the issue? The left-alignment of the equations?

Comment: Please make small complete document, which will show your issue. For sub equations: need to load `amsmat` or `mathtools` package and than in your case use `\begin{sunequations}\\begin{gather}equation 1 \\ equation 2 \\ etc \end{gather}\end{subequations}` ...

Comment: sorry i am not getting clearly...in this case where can i put my paragraph text?? I need to produce exactly as given in snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\tag` for the main equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% detach \eqref and \tag making
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\eqreftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\let\eqreftagform@\tagform@

\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{\textup{Eq.\ }(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:PR+cdeltat}
\lipsum*[3]% the paragraph before the equation
\begin{equation}
PR+c\delta t^s=\dots \tag{\ref{eq:PR+cdeltat}}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[4]% the paragraph between the equations
\begin{align}
P_1&=\dots \\
P_2&=\dots \\
P_3&=\dots \\
P_4&=\dots
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum[5]% text that follows

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid “Eq.” before the equation numbers: your readers will know what that number is for. Just remove the code from `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` if you choose to do this way.

You will use `\eqref{eq:PR+cdeltat}` for referring to the equation number, like in

```
Thus, four unknowns in~\eqref{eq:PR+cdeltat}, the three unknowns ...
```